# Insert h:mm pm/am time format into database using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm trying to insert a time written in h:mm am/pm format into a database that is stored as standard DATETIME format ( hh:mm:ss ) but I can't figure out how to convert the posted time into standard format so the database will accept it.

This is what I've been trying so far:

```
$title = $_POST['inputTitle'];
$date = $_POST['inputDate'];
$time = date('h:i:s a', strtotime($_POST['inputTime']));
$desc = $_POST['inputDesc'];


//msql query to insert data
$query = "INSERT INTO events(title, date, time, description) VALUES ('$title','$date','$time','$desc')";
```

but this doesn't work(time still won't submit) any ideas?

Comment: Try this date format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: echo the query, it will help you to debug.Also let us know the schema of event table

Comment: Standart DATETIME format - Y-m-d H:i:s but you try write TIME.
Maybe better to use TIME type in mysql?

Comment: like Dolbik already mentioned: what exactly is the datatype of `time` in your database?

Comment: datatype of time is DATATIME but I'm thinking I should change that to TIME as Dolbik stated, i didnt know there was a type solely for TIME which is where I initially went wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `TIME` type not `DATETIME` type.

`DATETIME` format is: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss`

[DATETIME format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

`TIME` format is: `hh:ii:ss`

[TIME format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html)

Comment: yep this solved the problem. thanks for your help guys! still getting the hang of setting up databases, twas a rookie mistake.

Comment: @CodyCarmichael yes, and you will make 10,000 rookie mistakes more before you can call yourself a professional. and even then you will make mistakes - but you can call them "pro mistakes" then.