# How to order by custom time format in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have to order a database table with a custom time format. 
 The time format used in the table is like this:

1:30:PM
8:35:PM
5:50:PM
7:00 PM

I tried the following, but it does not sort them all in the correct order.

```
            ->orderBy('time_schedule.start_time', 'asc');
```

After sorting the with the above method the result comes like

1:30:PM
5:50:PM
8:35:PM
7:00 PM

I'm not able to change the format saved, as i'm not working on that part of the application.

Also the data have to come sorted form laravel, cannot use front end sorting in my situation.

Please let me know whether there is a way to sort this with laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```html
addSelect(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('TIME_FORMAT(start_time,"%H:%i") as st_time'))->orderBy('st_time','asc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `STR_TO_DATE` function like:

```
SELECT
  start_time
FROM
  tablename
ORDER BY
  STR_TO_DATE(start_time, '%l:%i %p');
```

For this you have to use `raw` query.

[Reference](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use closer for that

```
->orderBy(function($item) {
     return Carbon::createFromFormat('g:i a', $item->date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s);
});
```

Comment: please show error, and please replace date to your column name

Comment: Hi, I tried this way, but got the following error:


_'ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given'_


I tried looking at the laravel docs for help, but couldn't find a closure with the orderby statement on docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SQL Date Function here:

```
ORDER BY DATE(time_schedule.start_time) DESC, time_schedule.start_time ASC
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add timestamp to database in custom format like 01:00 AM .all you to do is u need to format it to 24 hr then store it to database

so during retrieve order by clause will give you sorted order

```
    $time = '01:00 PM';
    $date = date_format(date_create($time),'H:i:s');
    \App\TableModel::insert(['start_time'=>$date]); 
    or
    DB::table('tablename')->insert(['start_time'=>$date]);

    retrive by order.......
    DB::table('tablename')->orderBy('start_time')->get();
```

for more information check ref:[Insert h:mm pm/am time format into database using MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735464/insert-hmm-pm-am-time-format-into-database-using-mysql)